# What is bad numbers for skew factor in Teradata?

Tags: sql, optimization, teradata, skew

I determine skew factor this way:

```
SELECT 
TABLENAME,
SUM(CURRENTPERM) /(1024*1024) AS CURRENTPERM, 
(100 - (AVG(CURRENTPERM)/MAX(CURRENTPERM)*100)) AS SKEWFACTOR 
FROM 
DBC.TABLESIZE 
WHERE DATABASENAME= <DATABASENAME> 
AND 
TABLENAME =<TABLENAME>  
GROUP BY 1;
```

For some tables with size ~600 Gb the skew factor is 30%. For table with size 10 Gb is pretty high 98%. How really is bad the number above? Is there any official article saying that more than  10% should be redistributed? I need it to substantiate requirements for mart developer. I have found only [this](http://digitalhalon.com/blog/2012/02/08/teradata-sql-to-estimate-skew-for-a-table-when-considering-different-primary-indexes/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Skew factor of *30* means there's about 40% more data on the max AMP compared to the average. This might still be acceptable (of course *it depends*), talk to your DBSa what they usually consider too big.

On the other hand *98* means there's 40 to 50 *times* more data on the max-AMP and that's waaaay to much.

This compares both ways to calculate skew:

```
SELECT
   t.DatabaseName
   ,t.TableName

   -- currently used diskspace in GB
   ,SUM(t.CurrentPerm) / 1024**3 (DEC(9,2)) AS CurrentPermGB

   -- currently needed diskspace in GB to store this table as standalone (due to Skew)
   ,MAX(t.CurrentPerm) / 1024**3 * (HASHAMP() + 1) (DEC(9,2)) AS SkewedPermGB

   ,SkewedPermGB - CurrentPermGB  AS WastedPermGB

   -- AMP with higehst disk usage
   ,MAX(t.MaxPermAMP) AS SkewedAMP

   -- skew factor, 1 = even distribution, 1.1 = max AMP needs 10% more space than the average AMP
   ,MAX(t.CurrentPerm) / NULLIF(AVG(t.CurrentPerm),0) (DEC(5,2)) AS SkewFactor

   -- skew factor, between 0 and 99.  Same calculation as WinDDI/ TD Administrator
   ,(100 - (AVG(t.CurrentPerm) / NULLIF(MAX(t.CurrentPerm),0) * 100)) (DEC(3,0)) AS SkewFactor_WINDDI
FROM
 (
   SELECT
      DatabaseName,
      TableName,
      CurrentPerm,
      CASE WHEN CurrentPerm = MAX(CurrentPerm) OVER (PARTITION BY DatabaseName, TableName) THEN vproc END AS MaxPermAMP
   FROM dbc.TableSizeV
   WHERE DatabaseName = '???' --
) AS t
GROUP BY 1,2
HAVING SkewFactor > 1.1 -- or whatever
   AND SkewedPermGB > 10 -- or whatever
ORDER BY WastedPermGB DESC
;
```

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any magic numbers, but having a table with 98% skew means that almost all the data lies in a single AMP, which means (1) you are loosing the performance advantages of a parallel database (2) you are creating an unbalanced load on the system.

Comment: I can't quote the exact source, but a created a script based on it (probably Teradata itself), where the you would want to watch the skew factor of 50+ on large tables.

Comment: @access_granted - So 50 is O.k.? 49? 48? 47?. Each has its impact